# Why airports are generally near sea?

Tags: gravity, potential, potential-energy

The generic way to measure the height is from the sea-level. If the airport is near the sea i.e. not at a very height from the sea, then the fuel required to make the air-plane above the sea level will be much. On the other hand, if the airport is quite above the sea level then the fuel required will be quite less to make the air-plane above the same sea level. However, I have seen that the airline charges are less when the port is near the sea. However, the airline charges are more when the port is far from the sea. Why is it so? Is my theory wrong?

Comment: That question seems off topic. The explanation to why planes fly does not required a certain altitude, unless air density and pressure reduction are of relevance. Otherwise this question seems to need a reshaping.

Comment: I think that there may be social and logistical reasons. That is, most big cities are near the sea in the first place...

Comment: ...and runways usually require a flat landscape often found in coastal areas...

Comment: @Qmechanic so... you're going to sign on to my Kickstarter campaign for a VTOL version of the 787?  :-)

Comment: Social and logistical reasons are the answer to this question, not physics. Airlines tend to charge less for travel between major airports than travel between lesser airports. Larger airports means larger airplanes (cheaper to operate), enhanced logistics (making ground operations cheaper), and greater competition for passengers (airlines have no choice but to charge less).

Comment: planes are noisy

Answer (score 4):

They aren't.   Major metropolises tend to be near water, as that was the primary method of transportation when said cities were founded.   Airports tend (gosh :-) ) to show up near major population centers.

I suspect Chicago, St. Louis, Denver, etc. would be amused at your claim that airports are near the sea!

Comment: I understand that Chicago is not near Sea. However, my question is do we save the cost when the airport is far above sea level. Consider the destination distance is same from both the locations.  Someone has said about wind. Does wind direction plays a vital role? For example, Jet engine leaves it mark because they fly in the very high layer of atmosphere. This means that the wind has no effect on the plane. Because at that layer, the wind is almost negligible. That's why there is no erosion and the plane marks are left behind.

Comment: Not to mention Dallas or Atlanta, or further afield, Delhi, Moscow, Mexico City, Toronto, etc. That said, about 44% of the world's population lives within 150 miles of the coast. This is the answer to your question, dexterous_stranger.

Comment: @dexterous_stranger  Ever heard of jet streams. Ever been one hour late because of contrary winds.

Answer (score 0):

It's considerably cheaper to fly from ATL (Atlanta, Georgia) to ORD (Chicago, Illinois) than it is to fly from VPS (Valparaiso, Florida) to BPT (Beaumont, Texas). It's not distance; Atlanta and Chicago are considerably further apart than are Valparaiso and Beaumont. It's not wind speed; Chicago is **the** windy city, after all. It's not oceans; Atlanta and Chicago are inland cities while Valparaiso and Beaumont are on or near the coast.

The distinguishing factor is size. ATL and ORD are huge airports served by a large number of airlines. VPS and BPT are small regional airports served by a small number of airlines.

This question is not about physics. It's about where people live. Four of the five largest cities and six of the ten largest cities in the United States are on or close to the coast. Almost half of humanity lives within 150 kilometers of the coast.

Answer (score -2):

I think that wind direction may have something to do with it. It will be easier to predict prevailing winds close to the coastline.